# Why would you use Transform-style: preserve-3d over z-index?

Tags: css

in the example in this website [Website link](http://www.htmq.com/css3/transform-style.shtml) they show a frog rotated over a green background. The one with transform-style: flat; is covered by the other element, but the transform-style: preserve-3d; goes above other elements.

The same effect could be accomplished with a z-index. Why would you use one over the other?

Comment: This may be too open ended a question, CSS has a tendency to have multiple ways of achieving similar effects and not all ways work in all situations or browsers - also you may consider actually inserting the images into this question - seeing the flood of kanji (was that Japanese? I think so) made me panic for a second that I was going to get spammed something, since I don't read kanji.

Comment: css-tricks article about [transform-style](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-style/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a cube that's transformed.  You can see the transform because it has as 100px border.

[image: 3d css box]

If we turn set it to flat, it then looks like this:

[image: flat box css 3d transform]